# Is it more efficient to specify the view location directly in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to have code that runs as efficiently as possible. I have views that are located in locations such as:

```
~/Areas/Administration/Views/Accounts/Create.cshtml
```

What I would like to know is has anyone looked into if it is more efficient to directly code the view location in action like this:

```
return View("~/Areas/Administration/Views/Accounts/Create.cshtml", vm);
```

If not coded like this then I believe it would search all the following locations first:

```
~/Areas/Administration/Views/Accounts/Create.aspx
~/Areas/Administration/Views/Accounts/Create.ascx
~/Areas/Administration/Views/Shared/Create.aspx
~/Areas/Administration/Views/Shared/Create.ascx
~/Views/Accounts/Create.aspx
~/Views/Accounts/Create.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Create.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Create.ascx
~/Areas/Administration/Views/Accounts/Create.cshtml
```

Comment: I am 90% sure your assumption is correct.

Comment: If you are hitting the database for *anything*, that will take 100,000 times (literally!) longer than executing any cached lookup in memory. Once you've cleaned up any excess SQL joins, SELECT N+1 scenarios and cached frequently used data in RAM, it's probably cheaper to throw money at faster hardware than spent it on programmer time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't worry about this and **never hardcode** your view locations like this. When running in `Release` mode ASP.NET MVC keeps those locations cached and it doesn't perform all those *expensive* lookups.

Comment: Would you recommend against using the constants created via T4MVC, then... they end up outputting the same thing, IIRC.

Comment: @Andrew Barber, personally I never use T4MVC, so cannot judge about its performance impacts but bearing in mind that there is no performance difference between the 2 in Release mode, if you are saying that using T4MVC you end up with a hardcoded view location there won't be any difference.

Comment: Oh, yes; good point! My "think it logically through" hat is in the car, today. +1

Answer (score 3):

Sam Saffron has [explored the performance impact](http://samsaffron.com/archive/2011/08/16/Oh+view+where+are+thou+finding+views+in+ASPNET+MVC3+) of view location in a blog post. The two conclusions:

- when running a release build, view locations are cached so there's really no performance penalty
- in debug mode, you can increase performance by removing support for view engines that you are not actually using (e.g. WebForms)

Therefore I second Darin's suggestion that hardcoding view locations will simply inconvenience you and not offer a performance benefit if you are doing everything else by the book.